# React Native Local Images not showing on android device

Tags: react-native

local images show in emulator iOS+Android but on android device just dont.
Any ideas?

```
<View style={styles.imgContainer}>
        <Image
          source={require('../../../../data/images/success.jpg')}
        />
      </View>
```

Comment: any updates about this?

Comment: Any updates @rei

Answer (score 0):

You need to bundle and install the build every time you add a resource like an image. The resource manager that bundles the JS does not do that in live preview.

You are probably updating the emulator but not the build for the device.

Answer (score 0):

To add a static image to your app, place it somewhere in your source code tree and reference it like this:

//relative path
├── button.js

```
   ├── img

      ├── check@2x.png

      ├── check@3x.png

 <Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```